# Listing Cross Enrollment in Resume

Tags: resume

Okay, so say you graduated from an online university, in Computer Science. You would list it out in their resume like so:

> BS. Computer Science in XXX University

However, you actually cross-enrolled in a local university. Should you list both institutions or should you just list his host institution? You took roughly the same amount of credits in both institutions.

I told him to just list his host university, however he did mention that the amount of credits were roughly the same, and this was not a simple  'take a class at another school' but a more involved 'cross-enrollment' program. What do you think would be preferred for listing his educational background?

Comment: Show both. If one is a 'technical school' and the other one is a 'core curriculum' school then the employer will be aware that the candidate has covered all the bases. In many parts of the US junior or community colleges handle the Freshman and Sophomore stuff and the Universities focus on the third and fourth year half of the majors.

Comment: @MeredithPoor Both were Universities - He officially graduated from one, while he cross-enrolled from the other. Would it still hold? Mind giving out how to format it in the resume? I'll accept it as an answer :)

Comment: I would list the degree as awarded by the university.  That's the achievement that's being claimed.  If you are asked for transcripts, then provide them with an explanation of the cross-enrollment.

Comment: @Secret - I would put the university issuing the degree first, and the cross-enrollment below it. If a recruiter is validating the degree program, they should know they need to contact two schools. People hardly care what school you were at for a given class, they just want to verify that you earned the degree you're claiming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that at some point you may be asked to prove your graduation using a diploma or transcript. So start with what does the diploma say. If it only mentions one institution that should be the one you mention in bold.

> BS. Computer Science from College/University mentioned on the Diploma.
>
> This was a joint program between mentioned college and other college. Courses were taken at both colleges and involved students from both institutions.

Of course many situations will only allow the basic info: level, school, major, and maybe year and city. These will be separate boxes and won't leave room for explanation. You will run into this with resume posting sites, company resume databases.

You will have to be careful not to oversell the degree. You may wish that you can put the more prestigious school on a form asking for the name of the school. But you should stick with what somebody will find when checking your background.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just expect to see the university where the degree was completed.....not the list of schools where you took credit classes.
 If they require a transcript, some universities have the combined versions as part of your student record. Otherwise providing two transcripts is not a big deal